# Login with facebook not working, cases refresh loop

Tags: facebook, api

On one of my websites, we have implemented the Login with facebook script. It was working fine till yesterday but suddenly there seems to be a problem with the script. If I am already logged in facebook, my website's page keeps on refreshing. If I log out of facebook then the refresh stops.

If this is facebook's script problem then I think there would be many other people who are facing this problem. Is any one here also facing this problem ?
please share and provide the solution if there is any.

Thanks

Ishan

Comment: Since you're talking about refreshing, I assume you aren't using FB.login and just redirecting the user to the login url, with a redirect_uri parameter or something. After they login, Facebook returns the user to your page.

Do you have any sort of check to see if the current visitor is already logged in? So something like `if (loggedIn) { displayPage(); } else { top.location.href = loginUrl }` ?

Also, what SDK are you using?

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue and we started using Fb.getLoginStatus instead of FB.Login and redirected the users based  on their status to the login page manually.

```
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
             if (response.status === 'connected') {
                 // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
                 // app, and response.authResponse supplies
                 // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
                 // request, and the time the access token 
                 // and signed request each expire
                 FB.api('/me', function (userDetails) {
                     LoadRegForm(userDetails);
                 });

             } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                 Rediret to facebook oauth page
              top.location.href = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fbappid"] %>&redirect_uri=<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fbcanvasurl"] %>&scope=email,user_birthday,user_education_history';

             } else {
                 // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
                 top.location.href = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fbappid"] %>&redirect_uri=<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fbcanvasurl"] %>&scope=email,user_birthday,user_education_history';
             }
```

You can even call the FB.Login function in the two else blocks instead of the redirect.